# In C# Serialization I need to Serialize Object that references object in other DLL without source code

Tags: c#, serialization, serializable

I need to Serialize Object that have another object as a field.

The problem is that this object being referenced is from another DLL that I don't have the code for it.
Therefore, I can't add the `[Serializable]` attribute to it.

Any suggestions on how o do it?
I was thinking to create my own `Serializer` class, is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, a custom serializer seems to be the appropriate approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use a reflector to reconstruct the code and add the serializable tag to it.

Comment: What if it is obfuscated? What if this code is in `System.dll`?

Comment: If the code is in System.dll, you can still reflect it...Download red gates .NET reflector and add into Visual Studio, and, as long as you know the class's name and the DLL it comes from, you can view the code for the class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SerializeSurrogate, see [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/dotnet/Surrogate_Serialization.aspx) for more information.